# ggplot2: conditionally changing linetype and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~group,             ~year,   ~value,  
  "group1",     "2010-2015",       70,
  "group2",     "2010-2015",       75,
  "group1",     "2015-2020",       72,
  "group2",     "2015-2020",       77,
  "group1",     "2020-2025",       74,
  "group2",     "2020-2025",       79,
  "group1",     "2025-2030",       76,
  "group2",     "2025-2030",       81)
```

I want to plot as *x*, year, and as *y*, value, *colored* by group, i.e,

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, value, color = group, group = group)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.1)
```

But I want the years "2020-2025" and "2025-2030" to be dashed lines.

Using the following code I get this error: "Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line"

```
df %>% 
  mutate(projection = year %in% c("2020-2025", "2025-2030")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = group, group = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = projection), size = 1.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this perhaps

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(projection = list("2010-2015" = F, "2015-2020" = c(T, F), "2020-2025" = T, "2025-2030" = T)[year]) %>% 
  unnest(projection) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = group, group = interaction(group, projection))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = projection), size = 1.1)
```

Output

[image]

---

Another form

```
df %>% 
  mutate(projection = list("2010-2015" = F, "2015-2020" = F, "2020-2025" = c(T, F), "2025-2030" = T)[year]) %>% 
  unnest(projection) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = group, group = interaction(group, projection))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = projection), size = 1.1)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation, so that readers arriving here from search can apply the concepts to their unique situation.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved via two `geom_line` layers and filtering the data to be displayed by each:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~group,             ~year,   ~value,  
  "group1",     "2010-2015",       70,
  "group2",     "2010-2015",       75,
  "group1",     "2015-2020",       72,
  "group2",     "2015-2020",       77,
  "group1",     "2020-2025",       74,
  "group2",     "2020-2025",       79,
  "group1",     "2025-2030",       76,
  "group2",     "2025-2030",       81)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(projection = year %in% c("2020-2025", "2025-2030"))

ggplot(mapping = aes(year, value, color = group, group = group)) +
  geom_line(data = filter(df1, !year %in% c("2025-2030")), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(data = filter(df1, projection), size = 1.1, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]